# Multiple file upload and zip them on the fly failed

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I have created multiple file uploader using html & php. Uploader functionality works fine but while I try to create a ZIP on the fly in order to add uploaded file into ZIP file. In that case, failed to create zip and add uploaded file into zip. I don't know why it's not working.

Please check my scripts below and let me know if I missed anything thanks in advance:

Html scripts:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>File Upload with Progress Bar</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// select file function only for styling up input[type="file"]
function select_file(){
  document.getElementById('image').click();
  return false;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<!--status message will appear here-->
<div class="status"></div>

<!--image upload form-->
<form class="pure-form" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

  <div class="upload">
    <a onclick="select_file()" class="pure-button">Choose a file</a>
    <input id="image" type="file"  multiple="multiple" name="files[]" >
  </div>

  <!--image preview-->
  <img src="" style="display:none">

  <input class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type="submit" value="Upload!">
</form>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Php Scripts:

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
        $path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory
 if (!file_exists('uploads')) {
 mkdir('uploads', 0777, true);
 }
 $max_file_size = 1024*10000; // 1024 byte= 1kb 1024*100 byte=100kb
 $count = 0;

              if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
{
$zip_path = 'download.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($zip_path,  ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
}

             foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {   
$filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$f];
$filecontent = file_get_contents($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f]);
$filetype = $_FILES['files']['type'][$f];
$filesize = $_FILES['files']['size'][$f];
        $fileext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);;
$zip->addFromString($filename, $filecontent);
//$zip->addFile('file_on_server.ext', 'second_file_name_within_archive.ext');

        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
$status[] ='Upload Fail: Unknown error occurred!';
continue; // Skip file if any error found
}          
if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
         if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
         $status[] = "$name is too large!.";
    continue; // Skip large files
    }
else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)){
    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
    $status[] = 'Image successfully uploaded!';
    }
    else {
    $status[] = 'Upload Fail: Unknown error occurred!';
    }
    }
  }
}
$zip->close();
}
else {
  $status[] = 'Bad request!';
}
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working probably download.zip file doesn't exist in your directory. 
Could you please create download.zip file or replace your following code then try again:

```
if ($zip->open($zip_path,ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) 
 {
  die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
}
```

With

```
 if ($zip->open($zip_path,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) 
{
 die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
}
```